# Array size changing when using String Split in Java

Tags: java, arrays, split, hashmap

The Assignment: Get two strings, separated by a comma. Save to a hashmap.

The Goal: Use a single try-catch block to keep the user from inputting the incorrect number of strings.

The Problem: The *register.put* line will throw a "IndexOutOfBounds" if only one string is provided, but if I provide 3+ strings it looks like the size of my array is increasing to handle additional line items (according to the debugger in IntelliJ IDEA). Is this an intended function of the *nextLine().split* function or am I missing something obvious? I understand I can use another loop to correct this, but I'm puzzled how "collector" can handle the following input:

Hello, World, Isn't, It, A, Great, Day?

```
    HashMap <String, String> register = new HashMap();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] collector = new String[2];


        try {
            collector = in.nextLine().split(",");
            register.put(collector[0], collector[1]);
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("\nYou didn't use the correct format!");
            System.out.println("Please use the format provided!");
        }
```

Comment: The array object is **not** changing size. Rather the collector variable is being assigned a **new** array when  you call `collector = in.nextLine().split(",");`. The previous 2 item empty array is discarded and wasted.

Comment: The split() method returns a String[].  So the collector [] array which is originally size of 2, is going to be re-assigned the String[] returned by the split method.

Comment: The reason for the exception is likely that the line you're reading when the exception occurs, is not what you think it is.  Debug it -- find out exactly what line is there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle the wrong inputs instead of catch the exception.

```
HashMap <String, String> register = new HashMap();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


String[] collector = in.nextLine().split(",");

// validate inputs here
if (collector.length == 2 ) {
    register.put(collector[0], collector[1]);
} else {
    System.out.println("\nYou didn't use the correct format!");
    System.out.println("Please use the format provided!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use try-catch only then you can use custom exceptions to handle inputs.

If so you can try like

```
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> register = new HashMap();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] collector;
    try {
        collector = in.nextLine().split(",");
        if (collector.length > 2) {
            throw new Test1().new MaxLimitCrossed();
        } else if (collector.length < 2) {
            throw new Test1().new MinLimitCrossed();
        }
        register.put(collector[0], collector[1]);
        System.out.println(register.toString());
    } catch (MinLimitCrossed e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (MaxLimitCrossed e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

class MaxLimitCrossed extends Exception {
    public MaxLimitCrossed() {
        super("Max Limit Crossed.");
    }
}

class MinLimitCrossed extends Exception {
    public MinLimitCrossed() {
        super("Min Limit Crossed.");
    }
}
}
```

Consider this as a reference, you can change custom exceptions as per your requirements. Simply tried to showcase how you can do this.